# Go back to the App component without react routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the  component that displays one button. Clicking this button loads the  component which has a back button. I now want to return back to the  component when this back button is clicked.

I am new to react and if I search online I see react-routing as the solution. Wouldn't simply rendering the  component from  component work? Just like  was rendered from ?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Yes I have and that's my question. Is it fine to simply render an App component from Home component when Home was rendered from App?

Comment: You want to switch between pages and change URL or only want to display different components with a button?

Answer (score 0):

Parent component has a state named isChildActive.

```
this.state = {isChildActive: false}
```

On the render of Parent you instantiate `<ChildComponent active={this.state.isChildActive} goBack={() => this.setState({isChildActive: false})} />`

And then you add to the `onClick` callback of the button at ParentComponent: `<button onClick ={() => this.setState({isChildActive:true})} />`

So that's the simple way of doing it. You own the state at your parent component because in react, data flows unidirectionally, from top to bottom. And then you pass a callback to your children components, to modify that parent owned state, when needed.

The best way of *routing* is using a library because it is not a simple task and you'll save a lot of time and headaches if you use a well-tested library. The industry standard is [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

Comment: Thanks @victor.js I'll try that. I could not find any documentation for the isChildActive property though. Can you point me to some doc online?

Comment: You can read the official documentation for React. It’s just a simple prop. https://www.freecodecamp.org has a nice and free course on react